# Writing a stored procedure on IBM iSeries

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have this SQL which creates the data set needed. I can use this in Crystal Reports; however, there are some issues with the limit of lines they allow. (There are other such groups of SQL statements). I include all the code just to get a sense of how many lines each section is.

However, 4 groups are running fine in CR time wise. But, I want to make this into a stored procedure.

Questions:

1. Is it SQL type of External.
2. Do I make a temp table to hold the data?
3. If not 2 then how do I access this data from Crystal Reports.

I am able to access a stored procedure from there.

Example SQL:

```
SELECT
count(*) as PROGR5PST,
(
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(OdQty#),0) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTDTA.OEORD1
  WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# AND OHCOM# = ODCOM# AND OHORD# = ODORD#
  AND TSSTAT IN('AEP','BGE')
  AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT')
  AND OHREQD < replace(char(current date, iso), '-', '')
  AND OHHLDC = ' '
  AND ODPRLC = 'ENG'
  AND substr(odprt#,1,5) <> 'NOENG' AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a    
WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP'))) AS PROGR5PUN,
(SELECT count(*) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTCCDTA.OETRA99  
WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# 
AND (otCOM# = OHCOM# AND OTORD#= OHORD# AND ottrnc = 'AQC')
AND TSSTAT IN('AEP','BGE')  
AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT') 
AND OHREQD < replace(char(current date, iso), '-', '')  AND OHHLDC = ' ' AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a    
WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP'))
) AS PROGR5TOD,
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(OdQty#),0) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTDTA.OEORD1
  WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# AND OHCOM# = ODCOM# AND OHORD# = ODORD#
  AND TSSTAT IN('AEP','BGE')
  AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT')
  AND OHREQD = replace(char(current date, iso), '-', '')
  AND OHHLDC = ' '
  AND ODPRLC = 'ENG'
  AND substr(odprt#,1,5) <> 'NOENG' AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a    
WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP'))
) AS PROGR5TUN,
(SELECT count(*) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTCCDTA.OETRA99  
WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# 
AND (otCOM# = OHCOM# AND OTORD#= OHORD# AND ottrnc = 'AQC')
AND TSSTAT IN('AEP','BGE')  
AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT') 
AND OHREQD = cast(replace(char(current date  + 1 day, iso), '-', '')as int)  AND OHHLDC = ' ' AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a    
WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP'))
) AS PROGR5TOM,
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(OdQty#),0) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTDTA.OEORD1
  WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# AND OHCOM# = ODCOM# AND OHORD# = ODORD#
  AND TSSTAT IN('AEP','BGE')
  AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT')
  AND OHREQD = cast(replace(char(current date  + 1 day, iso), '-', '') as int)
  AND OHHLDC = ' '
  AND ODPRLC = 'ENG'
  AND substr(odprt#,1,5) <> 'NOENG' AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a    
WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP'))
) AS PROGR5MUN,

(SELECT count(*) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTCCDTA.OETRA99  
WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# 
AND (otCOM# = OHCOM# AND OTORD#= OHORD# AND ottrnc = 'AQC')
AND TSSTAT IN('EAS','REL','SCC')  
AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT') 
AND OHREQD < replace(char(current date, iso), '-', '')  AND OHHLDC = ' ' AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a    
WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP'))
) AS LASGR5PST,

(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(OdQty#),0) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTDTA.OEORD1
  WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# AND OHCOM# = ODCOM# AND OHORD# = ODORD#
  AND TSSTAT IN('EAS','REL','SCC')
  AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT')
  AND OHREQD < replace(char(current date, iso), '-', '')
  AND OHHLDC = ' '
  AND ODPRLC = 'ENG'
  AND substr(odprt#,1,5) <> 'NOENG' AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a    
WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP'))
) AS LASGR5PUN,

(SELECT count(*) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTCCDTA.OETRA99  
WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# 
AND (otCOM# = OHCOM# AND OTORD#= OHORD# AND ottrnc = 'AQC')
AND TSSTAT IN('EAS','REL','SCC')  
AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT') 
AND OHREQD = replace(char(current date, iso), '-', '')  AND OHHLDC = ' ' AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a    
WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP'))
) AS LASGR5TOD,

(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(OdQty#),0) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTDTA.OEORD1
  WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# AND OHCOM# = ODCOM# AND OHORD# = ODORD#
  AND TSSTAT IN('EAS','REL','SCC')
  AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT')
  AND OHREQD = replace(char(current date, iso), '-', '')
  AND OHHLDC = ' '
  AND ODPRLC = 'ENG'
  AND substr(odprt#,1,5) <> 'NOENG' AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a    
WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP'))
) AS LASGR5TUN,

(SELECT count(*) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTCCDTA.OETRA99  
WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# 
AND (otCOM# = OHCOM# AND OTORD#= OHORD# AND ottrnc = 'AQC')
AND TSSTAT IN('EAS','REL','SCC')  
AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT') 
AND OHREQD = cast(replace(char(current date  + 1 day, iso), '-', '') as int) AND OHHLDC = ' ' AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a    
WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP'))
) AS LASGR5TOM,

(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(OdQty#),0) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTDTA.OEORD1
  WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# AND OHCOM# = ODCOM# AND OHORD# = ODORD#
  AND TSSTAT IN('EAS','REL','SCC')
  AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT')
  AND OHREQD = cast(replace(char(current date  + 1 day, iso), '-', '')as int)
  AND OHHLDC = ' '
  AND ODPRLC = 'ENG'
  AND substr(odprt#,1,5) <> 'NOENG' AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a    
WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP'))
) AS LASGR5MUN,

(SELECT count(*) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTCCDTA.OETRA99  
WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# 
AND (otCOM# = OHCOM# AND OTORD#= OHORD# AND ottrnc = 'AQC')
AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT') AND TSSTAT IN('ECT','STP')  
AND OHREQD < replace(char(current date, iso), '-', '')  
AND OHHLDC = ' 'AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a    
WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP'))
) AS PCKGR5PST,

(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(OdQty#),0) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTDTA.OEORD1  
WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# AND OHCOM# = ODCOM# AND OHORD# = ODORD#  
AND TSSTAT IN('ECT','STP')  
AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT')  
AND OHREQD < replace(char(current date, iso), '-', '')  
AND OHHLDC = ' '  AND ODPRT# = OdAls#  AND substr(odprt#,1,3) <> 'FRT'
AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# 
 FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a    
 WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP'))
) AS PCKGR5PUN,

(SELECT count(*) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTCCDTA.OETRA99  
WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# 
AND (otCOM# = OHCOM# AND OTORD#= OHORD# AND ottrnc = 'AQC')
AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT') AND TSSTAT IN('ECT','STP')  
AND OHREQD = replace(char(current date, iso), '-', '')  
AND OHHLDC = ' 'AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a    
WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP'))
) AS PCKGR5TOD,

(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(OdQty#),0) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTDTA.OEORD1  
WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# AND OHCOM# = ODCOM# AND OHORD# = ODORD#  
AND TSSTAT IN('ECT','STP')  
AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT')  
AND OHREQD = replace(char(current date, iso), '-', '')  
AND OHHLDC = ' '  AND ODPRT# = OdAls#  AND substr(odprt#,1,3) <> 'FRT'
AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# 
 FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a    
 WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP'))
) AS PCKGR5TUN,

(SELECT count(*) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTCCDTA.OETRA99  
WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# 
AND (otCOM# = OHCOM# AND OTORD#= OHORD# AND ottrnc = 'AQC')
AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT') AND TSSTAT IN('ECT','STP')  
AND OHREQD = cast(replace(char(current date  + 1 day, iso), '-', '')  as int)
AND OHHLDC = ' 'AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a    
WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP'))
) AS PCKGR5TOM,

(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(OdQty#),0) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTDTA.OEORD1  
WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# AND OHCOM# = ODCOM# AND OHORD# = ODORD#  
AND TSSTAT IN('ECT','STP')  
AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT')  
AND OHREQD = cast(replace(char(current date  + 1 day, iso), '-', '') as int)
AND OHHLDC = ' '  AND ODPRT# = OdAls#  AND substr(odprt#,1,3) <> 'FRT'
AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# 
 FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a    
 WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP'))
) AS PCKGR5MUN,


(SELECT count(*) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTCCDTA.OETRA99  
WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# 
AND (otCOM# = OHCOM# AND OTORD#= OHORD# AND ottrnc = 'AQC')
AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT') 
AND TSSTAT IN('EPT')  
AND OHREQD < replace(char(current date, iso), '-', '')  AND OHHLDC = ' '
AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a
    WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP')))AS ASSGR5PST,

(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(OdQty#),0) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTDTA.OEORD1  
WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# AND OHCOM# = ODCOM# AND OHORD# = ODORD#  
AND TSSTAT IN('EPT')  
AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT')  
AND OHREQD < replace(char(current date, iso), '-', '')  
AND OHHLDC = ' '  AND ODPRT# = OdAls#  AND substr(odprt#,1,3) <> 'FRT'
AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# 
 FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a    
 WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP'))
) AS ASSGR5PUN,

(SELECT count(*) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTCCDTA.OETRA99  
WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# 
AND (otCOM# = OHCOM# AND OTORD#= OHORD# AND ottrnc = 'AQC')
AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT') 
AND TSSTAT IN('EPT')  
AND OHREQD = replace(char(current date, iso), '-', '')  AND OHHLDC = ' '
AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a
    WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP'))) AS ASSGR5TOD,

(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(OdQty#),0) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTDTA.OEORD1  
WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# AND OHCOM# = ODCOM# AND OHORD# = ODORD#  
AND TSSTAT IN('EPT')  
AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT')  
AND OHREQD = replace(char(current date, iso), '-', '')  
AND OHHLDC = ' '  AND ODPRT# = OdAls#  AND substr(odprt#,1,3) <> 'FRT'
AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# 
 FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a    
 WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP'))
) AS ASSGR5TUN,

(SELECT count(*) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTCCDTA.OETRA99  
WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# 
AND (otCOM# = OHCOM# AND OTORD#= OHORD# AND ottrnc = 'AQC')
AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT') 
AND TSSTAT IN('EPT')  
AND OHREQD = cast(replace(char(current date  + 1 day, iso), '-', '') as int) AND OHHLDC = ' '
AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a
    WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP'))
) AS ASSGR5TOM,

(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(OdQty#),0) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTDTA.OEORD1  
WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# AND OHCOM# = ODCOM# AND OHORD# = ODORD#  
AND TSSTAT IN('EPT')  
AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT')  
AND OHREQD =cast(replace(char(current date  + 1 day, iso), '-', '')  as int)
AND OHHLDC = ' '  AND ODPRT# = OdAls#  AND substr(odprt#,1,3) <> 'FRT'
AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# 
 FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a    
 WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP'))
) AS ASSGR5MUN,


(SELECT count(*) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTCCDTA.OETRA99  
WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# 
AND (otCOM# = OHCOM# AND OTORD#= OHORD# AND ottrnc = 'AQC')
AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT') 
AND TSSTAT IN('CAT')  
AND OHREQD < replace(char(current date, iso), '-', '')  AND OHHLDC = ' '
AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a
    WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP'))
) AS SHPGR5PST,

(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(OdQty#),0) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTDTA.OEORD1  
WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# AND OHCOM# = ODCOM# AND OHORD# = ODORD#  
AND TSSTAT IN('CAT')  
AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT')  
AND OHREQD < replace(char(current date, iso), '-', '')  
AND OHHLDC = ' '  AND ODPRT# = OdAls#  AND substr(odprt#,1,3) <> 'FRT'
AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# 
 FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a    
 WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP'))
) AS SHPGR5PUN,

(SELECT count(*) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTCCDTA.OETRA99  
WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# 
AND (otCOM# = OHCOM# AND OTORD#= OHORD# AND ottrnc = 'AQC')
AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT') 
AND TSSTAT IN('CAT')  
AND OHREQD = replace(char(current date, iso), '-', '')  AND OHHLDC = ' '
AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a
    WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP'))
) AS SHPGR5TOD,

(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(OdQty#),0) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTDTA.OEORD1  
WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# AND OHCOM# = ODCOM# AND OHORD# = ODORD#  
AND TSSTAT IN('CAT')  
AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT')  
AND OHREQD = replace(char(current date, iso), '-', '')  
AND OHHLDC = ' '  AND ODPRT# = OdAls#  AND substr(odprt#,1,3) <> 'FRT'
AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# 
 FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a    
 WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP'))
) AS SHPGR5TUN,

(SELECT count(*) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTCCDTA.OETRA99  
WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# 
AND (otCOM# = OHCOM# AND OTORD#= OHORD# AND ottrnc = 'AQC')
AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT') 
AND TSSTAT IN('CAT')  
AND OHREQD = cast(replace(char(current date  + 1 day, iso), '-', '') as int) AND OHHLDC = ' '
AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a
    WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP'))
) AS SHPGR5TOM,

(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(OdQty#),0) FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTDTA.OEORD1  
WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# AND OHCOM# = ODCOM# AND OHORD# = ODORD#  
AND TSSTAT IN('CAT')  
AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT')  
AND OHREQD = cast(replace(char(current date  + 1 day, iso), '-', '')  as int)
AND OHHLDC = ' '  AND ODPRT# = OdAls#  AND substr(odprt#,1,3) <> 'FRT'
AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# 
 FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a    
 WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP'))
) AS SHPGR5MUN,


(SELECT count(*) FROM  ASTCCDTA.OEORH48        
WHERE OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT')   
AND OHREQD < replace(char(current date, iso), '-', '') AND OHHLDC <> ' '
) AS HLDGR5PST,

(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(OdQty#),0) FROM  ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTDTA.OEORD1         
WHERE OHCOM# = ODCOM# AND OHORD# = ODORD# AND ODPRT# = OdAls# 
AND substr(odprt#,1,3) <> 'FRT'AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT')  
AND OHREQD <replace(char(current date, iso), '-', '') AND OHHLDC <> ' ' 
) AS HLDGR5PUN,

(SELECT count(*) FROM  ASTCCDTA.OEORH48        
WHERE OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT')   
AND OHREQD = replace(char(current date, iso), '-', '') AND OHHLDC <> ' '
) AS HLDGR5TOD,

(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(OdQty#),0) FROM  ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTDTA.OEORD1         
WHERE OHCOM# = ODCOM# AND OHORD# = ODORD# AND ODPRT# = OdAls# 
AND substr(odprt#,1,3) <> 'FRT'AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT')  
AND OHREQD =replace(char(current date, iso), '-', '') AND OHHLDC <> ' ' 
) AS HLDGR5TUN,

(SELECT count(*) FROM  ASTCCDTA.OEORH48        
WHERE OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT')   
AND OHREQD =cast(Right(Replace(Char(current date + 1 day, ISO), '-', ''),8)as int) AND OHHLDC <> ' '
) AS HLDGR5TOM,

(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(OdQty#),0) FROM  ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTDTA.OEORD1         
WHERE OHCOM# = ODCOM# AND OHORD# = ODORD# AND ODPRT# = OdAls# 
AND substr(odprt#,1,3) <> 'FRT'AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT')  
AND OHREQD =cast(Right(Replace(Char(current date + 1 day, ISO), '-', ''),8)as int)  AND OHHLDC <> ' ' 
) AS HLDGR5MUN

FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48,ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2,ASTCCDTA.OETRA99  
WHERE OHCOM# = TSCOM# AND OHORD# = TSORD# 
AND (otCOM# = OHCOM# AND OTORD#= OHORD# AND ottrnc = 'AQC')
AND TSSTAT IN('AEP','BGE')  
AND OHORDT IN('FCH','FIT') 
AND OHREQD < replace(char(current date, iso), '-', '')  AND OHHLDC = ' ' AND OHORD# in(SELECT a.TSORD# FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a    
WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP'))
```

Comment: That's an intimidating amount of SQL.  Chopping 14.5 KiB off it leaving an incomplete fragment of an SQL statement is not really an improvement, though reducing the amount of SQL would be sensible.

Answer (score 2):

Not only is this query overly long, it's also potentially much slower than it needs to be, due to the constant subqueries.  You should actually be able to combine most of them, which should help both areas.

Note that I'm making guesses as to which tables contain which fields.  This is only possible because it's clear that the iSeries tradition of using table-specific prefixes is in effect.  That's a bad thing long term, you'd be better off using proper names and using aliases.

It would also be *extremely* helpful to see some sample data, because that influences what has to be pre-aggregated, and what can be left as-is.  I'm also worried that you may have one or more typos - the subqueries that sum are doing different comparisons than the counting ones (`ODPRLC = 'ENG'` versus `ottrnc = 'AQC'`).  This means the aggregates aren't measuring over the same things, which is problematic.

Warning - without more information, it's impossible for me to know if this should work or not.  Everything that follows is a guess, plain and simple.

First, let's construct a small virtual table for the date ranges:

```
WITH Time_Slice AS (SELECT slice, 
                           CAST(REPLACE(CHAR(s, ISO), '-', '') AS INT) AS startsOn, 
                           CAST(REPLACE(CHAR(e, ISO), '-', '') AS INT) AS endsOn
                    FROM (VALUES (1, CAST('0001-01-01' AS DATE), CURRENT_DATE),
                                 (2, CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_DATE + 1 DAY),
                                 (3, CURRENT_DATE + 1 DAY, CURRENT_DATE + 2 DAYS)) 
                         n(slice, s, e))
```

I'm assuming the columns compared against (`OHREQD`) are actually integer, and not character of some sort - you aren't consistent with the comparisons.  Note that this makes it easy to modify the query if that column is changed to an actual `DATE` type.

We also want a table that can be used for grouping transaction statuses:

```
Status_Group AS (SELECT grouping, status
                 FROM (VALUES ('PRO', 'AEP'),
                              ('PRO', 'BGE'),
                              ('LAS', 'EAS'),
                              ('LAS', 'REL'),
                              ('LAS', 'SCC'),
                              ('PCK', 'ECT'), 
                              ('PCK', 'STP'),
                              ('ASS', 'EPT'),
                              ('SHP', 'CAT')) g(grouping, status))
```

Table `OEORH48` is "constant" - it always has the same comparisons being made on it.  This means the rows it returns will always be the same.  We're not going to turn it into a CTE though, because of the tables that join to it.  However, the new base of the query is this:

```
SELECT ....
FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48 Order_History
JOIN Time_Slice
     ON Order_History.ohReqD >= Time_Slice.startsOn
        AND Order_History.ohReqD < Time_Slice.endsOn
......
WHERE Order_History.ohOrdT IN('FCH', 'FIT')
      AND Order_History.ohHldC = ' '
```

(we'll be making use of what `Time_Slice` exposes later).

The following sub-subquery is problematic:

```
SELECT a.TSORD# 
FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 a    
WHERE a.tsstat IN('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP')
```

If we assume `TSORD#` is unique in the given table, then it's unnecessary (because you already have a condition in the outer subquery), and in some cases *actually works against you*.  If it's not, then some of the time the same record will be considered both times, which seems... unwanted.  I'm going to eliminate it where I can, but can't completely.  Regardless, we only need to get this information once, create another CTE (there's a reason for this):

```
Other_Transaction_Status AS (SELECT DISTINCT tsOrd#
                             FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2
                             WHERE tsStat IN ('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP'))
```

This is because of the interplay of the final set of columns (that don't care about other statuses).

Table `TRNSTAT2` is also constant.  It's repeated 6 times each for groupings `'AEP', 'BGE'`, `'EAS', 'REL', 'SCC'`, `'ECT', 'STP'`, `'EPT'`, and `'CAT'`.  We can combine all of them:

```
.........
JOIN ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 Transaction_Status
     ON Transaction_Status.tsCom# = Order_History.ohCom#
        AND Transaction_Status.tsOrd# = Order_History.ohOrd#
        AND Transaction_Status.tsStat IN('AEP', 'BGE', 'EAS', 'REL', 'SCC', 'ECT', 'STP', 'EPT', 'CAT')
..............
```

Our two "detail" tables, `OEORD1` and `OETRA99`, are repeated multiple times.  We can reduce them to these CTEs (not sure about if the names I've chosen are correct):

```
Order_Detail_ENG AS (SELECT odCom#, odOrd#, SUM(odQty#) AS quantity
                     FROM ASTDTA.OEORD1
                     WHERE odPrLC = 'ENG'
                           AND SUBSTR(odPrt#, 1, 5) <> 'NOENG'
                     GROUP BY odCom#, odOrd#)

Order_Detail_Other AS (SELECT odCom#, odOrd#, SUM(odQty#) AS quantity
                       FROM ASTDTA.OEORD1
                       WHERE odPrT# = OdAls#
                             AND SUBSTR(odPrT#, 1, 3) <> 'FRT'
                       GROUP BY odCom#, odOrd#)

Order_Transaction AS (SELECT otCom#, otOrd#, COUNT(*) as quantity
                      FROM ASTCCDTA.OETRA99
                      WHERE otTrnC = 'AQC'
                      GROUP BY otCom#, otOrd#)
```

All together these were referenced 30 times.

Now, to put everything together, we're going to make use of a nice property of both `SUM(...)` and `COUNT(<expression>)` - they ignore null rows!  So long as at least one row is present, they return a numeric result.  With this, we can turn off what rows are being counted:

```
WITH Time_Slice AS (SELECT slice, 
                           CAST(REPLACE(CHAR(s, ISO), '-', '') AS INT) AS startsOn, 
                           CAST(REPLACE(CHAR(e, ISO), '-', '') AS INT) AS endsOn
                    FROM (VALUES (1, CAST('0001-01-01' AS DATE), CURRENT_DATE),
                                 (2, CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_DATE + 1 DAY),
                                 (3, CURRENT_DATE + 1 DAY, CURRENT_DATE + 2 DAYS)) 
                         n(slice, s, e)),

     Status_Group AS (SELECT grouping, status
                      FROM (VALUES ('PRO', 'AEP'),
                                   ('PRO', 'BGE'),
                                   ('LAS', 'EAS'),
                                   ('LAS', 'REL'),
                                   ('LAS', 'SCC'),
                                   ('PCK', 'ECT'), 
                                   ('PCK', 'STP'),
                                   ('ASS', 'EPT'),
                                   ('SHP', 'CAT')) g(grouping, status)),

     Other_Transaction_Status AS (SELECT DISTINCT tsOrd#
                                  FROM ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2
                                  WHERE tsStat IN ('AEP','BGE','EAS','REL','STP')),

     Order_Detail_ENG AS (SELECT odCom#, odOrd#, SUM(odQty#) AS quantity
                          FROM ASTDTA.OEORD1
                          WHERE odPrLC = 'ENG'
                                AND SUBSTR(odPrt#, 1, 5) <> 'NOENG'
                          GROUP BY odCom#, odOrd#),

     Order_Detail_Other AS (SELECT odCom#, odOrd#, SUM(odQty#) AS quantity
                            FROM ASTDTA.OEORD1
                            WHERE odPrT# = OdAls#
                                  AND SUBSTR(odPrT#, 1, 3) <> 'FRT'
                            GROUP BY odCom#, odOrd#),

     Order_Transaction AS (SELECT otCom#, otOrd#, COUNT(*) as quantity
                           FROM ASTCCDTA.OETRA99
                           WHERE otTrnC = 'AQC'
                           GROUP BY otCom#, otOrd#)


SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 1
                     AND Status_Group.grouping = 'PRO'
                THEN Order_Transaction.quantity END) AS PROGR5PST,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 1
                     AND Status_Group.grouping = 'PRO'
                THEN Order_Detail_ENG.quantity END) AS PROGR5PUN,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 2
                     AND Status_Group.grouping = 'PRO'
                THEN Order_Transaction.quantity END) AS PROGR5TOD,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 2
                     AND Status_Group.grouping = 'PRO'
                THEN Order_Detail_ENG.quantity END) AS PROGR5TUN,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 3
                     AND Status_Group.grouping = 'PRO'
                THEN Order_Transaction.quantity END) AS PROGR5TOM,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 3
                     AND Status_Group.grouping = 'PRO'
                THEN Order_Detail_ENG.quantity END) AS PROGR5MUN,

       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 1
                     AND Status_Group.grouping = 'LAS'
                THEN Order_Transaction.quantity END) AS LASGR5PST,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 1
                     AND Status_Group.grouping = 'LAS'
                THEN Order_Detail_ENG.quantity END) AS LASGR5PUN,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 2
                     AND Status_Group.grouping = 'LAS'
                THEN Order_Transaction.quantity END) AS LASGR5TOD,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 2
                     AND Status_Group.grouping = 'LAS'
                THEN Order_Detail_ENG.quantity END) AS LASGR5TUN,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 3
                     AND Status_Group.grouping = 'LAS'
                THEN Order_Transaction.quantity END) AS LASGR5TOM,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 3
                     AND Status_Group.grouping = 'LAS'
                THEN Order_Detail_ENG.quantity END) AS LASGR5MUN,

       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 1
                     AND Status_Group.grouping = 'PCK'
                THEN Order_Transaction.quantity END) AS PCKGR5PST,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 1
                     AND Status_Group.grouping = 'PCK'
                THEN Order_Detail_Other.quantity END) AS PCKGR5PUN,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 2
                     AND Status_Group.grouping = 'PCK'
                THEN Order_Transaction.quantity END) AS PCKGR5TOD,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 2
                     AND Status_Group.grouping = 'PCK'
                THEN Order_Detail_Other.quantity END) AS PCKGR5TUN,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 3
                     AND Status_Group.grouping = 'PCK'
                THEN Order_Transaction.quantity END) AS PCKGR5TOM,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 3
                     AND Status_Group.grouping = 'PCK'
                THEN Order_Detail_Other.quantity END) AS PCKGR5MUN,

       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 1
                     AND Status_Group.grouping = 'ASS'
                THEN Order_Transaction.quantity END) AS ASSGR5PST,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 1
                     AND Status_Group.grouping = 'ASS'
                THEN Order_Detail_Other.quantity END) AS ASSGR5PUN,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 2
                     AND Status_Group.grouping = 'ASS'
                THEN Order_Transaction.quantity END) AS ASSGR5TOD,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 2
                     AND Status_Group.grouping = 'ASS'
                THEN Order_Detail_Other.quantity END) AS ASSGR5TUN,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 3
                     AND Status_Group.grouping = 'ASS'
                THEN Order_Transaction.quantity END) AS ASSGR5TOM,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 3
                     AND Status_Group.grouping = 'ASS'
                THEN Order_Detail_Other.quantity END) AS ASSGR5MUN,

       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 1
                     AND Status_Group.grouping = 'SHP'
                THEN Order_Transaction.quantity END) AS SHPGR5PST,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 1
                     AND Status_Group.grouping = 'SHP'
                THEN Order_Detail_Other.quantity END) AS SHPGR5PUN,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 2
                     AND Status_Group.grouping = 'SHP'
                THEN Order_Transaction.quantity END) AS SHPGR5TOD,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 2
                     AND Status_Group.grouping = 'SHP'
                THEN Order_Detail_Other.quantity END) AS SHPGR5TUN,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 3
                     AND Status_Group.grouping = 'SHP'
                THEN Order_Transaction.quantity END) AS SHPGR5TOM,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 3
                     AND Status_Group.grouping = 'SHP'
                THEN Order_Detail_Other.quantity END) AS SHPGR5MUN,

       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 1 THEN 1 END) AS HLDGR5PST,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 1
                THEN Order_Detail_Other.quantity END) AS HLDGR5PUN,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 2 THEN 1 END) AS HLDGR5TOD,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 2
                THEN Order_Detail_Other.quantity END) AS HLDGR5TUN,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 3 THEN 1 END) AS HLDGR5TOM,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Time_Slice.slice = 3
                THEN Order_Detail_Other.quantity END) AS HLDGR5MUN,

FROM ASTCCDTA.OEORH48 Order_History
JOIN Time_Slice
  ON Order_History.ohReqD >= Time_Slice.startsOn
     AND Order_History.ohReqD < Time_Slice.endsOn
LEFT JOIN (ASTCCDTA.TRNSTAT2 Transaction_Status
           JOIN Status_Group
             ON Status_Group.status = Transactino_Status.ts.Stat
           JOIN Other_Transaction_Status 
             ON Other_Transaction_Status.tsOrd# = Transaction_Status.tsOrd#) Transaction_Status
       ON Transaction_Status.tsCom# = Order_History.ohCom#
          AND Transaction_Status.tsOrd# = Order_History.ohOrd#
          AND Transaction_Status.tsStat IN('AEP', 'BGE', 'EAS', 'REL', 'SCC', 'ECT', 'STP', 'EPT', 'CAT')
LEFT JOIN Order_Detail_ENG
       ON Order_Detail_ENG.odCom# = Order_History.ohCom#
          AND Order_Detail_ENG.odOrd# = Order_History.ohOrd#
LEFT JOIN Order_Detail_Other
       ON Order_Detail_Other.odCom# = Order_History.ohCom#
          AND Order_Detail_Other.odOrd# = Order_History.ohOrd#
LEFT JOIN Order_Transacion
       ON Order_Transaction.otCom# = Order_History.ohCom#
          AND Order_Transaction.otOrd# = Order_History.ohOrd#
WHERE Order_History.ohOrdT IN('FCH', 'FIT')
      AND Order_History.ohHldC = ' '
```

(Note:  I've assumed that the fact that `PROGR5PST` and `PROGR5TOD` would return the same value to be a typo - they were both considering the same set of rows.  It looked like you were missing the second "today" value, which I've assumed was supposed to be `PROGR5TOD`.  You may need to adjust this.)

Some other things to consider: It's possible this could be faster.   A bit of that is because of how `SUM(CASE...)` has to be run by the system.  It's possible to do these conditions as part of a *join*, but then you end up with 30 table references.  You could also do things like aggregate by `slice` and `grouping` first (as a subquery), and then pivot out this way.  Experiment, see what works, and if this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Read the answer by @Clockwork-Muse.  There is a lot of thought put into it, and some very good advice about how to structure SQL, and more importantly, about how to *think* about SQL.

> Is it SQL type of External.

An External procedure is written in any language other than SQL.  If you want to do this all in SQL, you'd create an SQL procedure.  If you prefer to embed your SQL into an RPG program (for example) you'd create an external procedure.

> Do I make a temp table to hold the data?

**No!**  If there is a wrong way to write a stored procedure, that would be it.  The 30 year old concept of loading a work file, sorting it and then printing it is a very poor match for the way SQL operates.

> If not 2 then how do I access this data from Crystal Reports.

You create a result set.  Here is a simple SQL example to get you started.  There are many RPG examples on the web.

```
create procedure lib/procedure_name
(in ...whatever... char(10))                                    
 language sql                                         
 dynamic result sets 1                                
 begin                                                
 declare c1 cursor for 
   SELECT * FROM LIBRARY/TABLE ORDER BY 1;
 open c1;                                             
 return;                                              
 end;
```